# qt qwebview unable to display korean

Tags: qt, printing, locale

I made a simple qwebview application.

as shown blow, I can't see korean correctly.

do I have to configure settings?

it's just normal QWebView application.
(on Windows 8, Qt 5.1)

thanks

[image: qwebview language problem]

Comment: I realize that QWebView can't display korean in <span> tag. korean with <a> tag works great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

google main page: able to display korean

google search result page: unable to display korean

I compare html source of two page(one for working one, one for not working one)

I realize that html from working one specify font-family

and the font family include 굴림 font.

other browser such as Internet Explorer, Google Chrome, Firefox has a feature called font fallback.

but webkit hasn't.

this was the reason

I add some configure code to my application and it works!

```
wv->settings()->globalSettings()->setFontFamily(QWebSettings::SansSerifFont,"굴림");
```

so my mainwindow.cpp looks like this

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QtWebKitWidgets/QWebView>
#include <QtWebKitWidgets/QWebFrame>

QWebView *wv;
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    wv = new QWebView;
    wv->settings()->globalSettings()->setFontFamily(QWebSettings::SansSerifFont,"굴림");
    wv->show();
    QUrl url("http://youtube.co.kr");
    wv->load(url);

}
```